# Access control of Activity in Service Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-broadcast

I am new to android. i know that we can not access control of activity from service. But i want to change the ImageSource of the button whenever i call the method of the service.

here is the method that i created in service :

```
public void play()
    {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.pause();
                // Changing button image to play button
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play); // not allowed
            }
        } else {
            // Resume song
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.start();
                // Changing button image to pause button
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause); // not allowed
            }
        }
    }
```

in activity i am calling this method on play button click. How to implement this functionality in service. how can i change the image source of the button. Please clear my doubt. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom event object for those events and register your activity as listener.

Note: Don't forget to unregister it because it might cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public static MainActivity mThis;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mThis = this;

}
```

}

```
public void play()
{

 Button btnPlay=((Button)MainActivity.mThis.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay));
  if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.pause();
        // Changing button image to play button

        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play); 
    }
} else {
    // Resume song
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.start();
        // Changing button image to pause button
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created class which extends service. Service is controlling mediaplayer.